# Failed sending workitem with azure blob storage

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

I'm trying to use design automation api using postman with this sample appBundle from https://github.com/augustogoncalves/forge-customproperty-revit but I'm using azure blob storage to store the revit file and upload the resulting json file, I was able to send the workitem, however the result returns **failedupload**. Looking into the log, it looks like execution was successful but the resulting json file was not uploaded to the azure blob storage due to missing required header. Kindly see the part of the log below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error><Code>MissingRequiredHeader</Code><Message>An HTTP header that&apos;s mandatory for this request is not specified.
RequestId:538e885c-001e-0061-38b0-fa8bac000000
Time:2023-10-09T13:02:55.6873032Z</Message><HeaderName>x-ms-blob-type</HeaderName></Error>
```

I tried to add the header **x-ms-blob-type** with value **BlockBlob** in postman but still got the same error at the end.[image]

I really appreciate your help on this.

Thanks

Comment: You have to add the header `x-ms-blob-type` to the workitem argument instead of adding it to the work item call. If you share the argument details in your description, I can point out where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the header x-ms-blob-type to the workitem argument instead of adding it to the workitem call. See example in [workitem documentation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/workitems-POST/).

```json
"OutputIpt": {
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/2922c578-da22-4a35-a943-6cfeb4484009?region=US",
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "",
        "Content-type": "application/octet-stream"
    },
}
```

In your case you will have:

```json
"jsonArgName": {
    "url": "https://azure.com/url/path",
    "headers": {
        "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
    },
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul, I really appreciate your help, that solved my issue.